# Check if its users first time on site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find out if its the users first time on my webpage. I am currently storing a variable in local storage and checking if its null or not but it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer. What other method can I use to accomplish this?

```
    var str_count = localStorage.getItem("count");
    if (str_count == null || str_count == "null")
    {
               // Do something
             }
```

Comment: you can always use a cookie...

Comment: Wouldn't this be an unreliable method to do such a test? Just asking, cause of cleaning out browsers and junk like this.

Comment: @MikeRamirez there is no other way, if browser was cleaned then it will be considered as a new user.

Comment: Ya it is unreliable, but for my purpose that is all right. I just need to know when they first come to set up some local storage variables. If they clear out there browser down the road its not a big deal to re-create them, but it won't work if I have to do on each page load.

Comment: the above code gives the error:

Unable to get value of the property 'getItem': object is null or undefined

Comment: You could try cookies -- same issue (gets cleared when browser cache is dumped. You could try testing to see if a fetched image is still in cache -- same issue (gets cleared when browser cache is dumped). First is hard to catch. First time since the browser cache was cleared is easier -- but very different.

Comment: This might be a bit overkill for your use case, but you could also use [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `cookie` with long expiration date is definitely more reliable that using `localStorage` as it is not yet supported by older browsers.

Check this code:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Read more about cookies [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie with

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + exp + "; path=/";
```

<strike>More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp</strike>

More info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: I prefer this guide instead http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html why `NOT` w3schools here http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: This cookie will be removed when you close the browser. Set `expires` to make it valuable.

Comment: @AhmedJolani, VisioN: I have incorporated your changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Greg said, the better solution is to set and get cookie values. Here's two functions to do this:

```
setCookie = function(){
    var args = arguments,
    name = (args[0] ? args[0] : '') + '=',
    _value = args[1] ? escape(args[1]) : '',
    value = _value + ';',
    expires = args[2] ? 'expires=' + args[2].toUTCString() + ';' : '',
    path = args[3] ? 'path=' + args[3] + ';' : '',
    domain = args[4] ? 'domain=' + args[4] + ';' : '',
    secure = args[5] ? 'secure;' : '',
    newCookie = name + value + expires + path + domain + secure;
    document.cookie = newCookie.match(/[a-z||A-Z]/) ? newCookie : ''
    return _value;
},
getCookie = function(name){
    if(!name || name.replace(/[^a-z|0-9|çáéíóúãõâêîôûàèìòùäëïöü]/,'')=='*') return document.cookie;
    var ck = ' ' + document.cookie + ' ',
    pos = ck.search(' ' + name + '='),
    pos = (pos!=-1) ? pos + 1 : ck.length,
    ck = ck.substring(pos-1,ck.length),
    end = (ck.search('; ')!=-1) ? ck.search('; ') : ck.length,
    value = ck.substring(((ck.search('=')!=-1) ? (ck.search('=')+1) : end),end);
    return unescape((value[value.length-1]==' ') ? value.substring(0,value.length-1) : value);
}
```

They're crossbrowser functions. To use `getCookie` function, just use the `name` parameter, and with the `setCookie` function, use the `name,value,expires,path,domain,secure` parameters